# Expose Blob field in business central via web services

Tags: dynamics-business-central

is it possible to expose a Blob Field via web service ?

I have a custom table in BC 22, one field is a Blob type.
I created a page in Visual studio code, that contains all the field i need to expose (also the Blob field). I published the page, and under web service settings, i added the page.
Then i try to connect to web service page, i see no reference to the blob field.

This is the table
`I have a custom table in BC 22, one field is a Blob type.
I created a page in Visual studio code, that contains all the field i need to expose (also the Blob field). I published the page, and under web service settings, i added the page.
Then i try to connect to web service page, i see no reference to the blob field.

This is the table

```
table 50500 "Test Blob"
{
    DataClassification = ToBeClassified;
    DataPerCompany = false;

    fields
    {
        field(1; NomeFileDaSpedire; Text[250])
        {
            Caption = 'NomeFileDaSpedire';
        }
        field(2; "Campo modifica"; Text[250])
        {
            Caption = 'NomeFileDaSpedire';
        }
        field(16; "BlobFile"; Blob)
        {
            Caption = 'BlobFile';
        }
    }
    keys
    {
        key(PK; NomeFileDaSpedire)
        {
            Clustered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the page

```
page 50500 "Test Blob PAge"
{
    ApplicationArea = All;
    Caption = 'Test Blob Page';
    PageType = List;
    SourceTable = "Test Blob";
    UsageCategory = Documents;

    layout
    {
        area(content)
        {
            repeater(General)
            {
                field(BlobFile; Rec.BlobFile)
                {
                    ToolTip = 'Specifies the value of the BlobFile field.';
                }
                field(NomeFileDaSpedire; Rec.NomeFileDaSpedire)
                {
                    ToolTip = 'Specifies the value of the NomeFileDaSpedire field.';
                }
                field("Campo modifica"; Rec."Campo modifica")
                {
                    ToolTip = 'Specifies the value of the NomeFileDaSpedire field.';
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

When i try to go to webservice page i see :

[Web Service Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N6mv.png)

No mention to "blobfile" field.

Is it possible to do what i wanted to do ?
If yes , what i'm doing wrong ?

Fabrizio